# How can I render Angular Material components using renderer

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on a chatbot that dynamically creates divs using this.renderer.createElement('div') and appending it to a div container. I now want to add a date pickerinside the div container that can be scrolled. Hence, I cannot add an Angular material tag in the template which will make it static with respect to the scrollable div. I tried using input type="date" but it is not compatible with IE.
I am currently rendering divs like this:

```
let maindivElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.appendChild(this.conversations.nativeElement, maindivElement);
```

However, this does not seem to work:

```
  let divElement=this.renderer.createElement('div');
  let datepickerElement=this.renderer.createElement('mat-datepicker');
  this.renderer.appendChild(divElement, datepickerElement);
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.conversations.nativeElement, divElement);
```

Is there anyway to create such custom tags dynamically. I tried other npm packages too but they too don't display anything unless defined in the template.
**I imported the modules properly**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a component containing a material component using appendchild..

Comment: You can dynamically add elements but they will not be rendered with angular 
i.e. adding a `<hr>` works, adding a `<mat-icon>` does not render an icon.